# Горизонтльный скролл на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-events

Как сделать горизонтальный скролл в блоке средствами нативного js или jquery?

Comment: Можно вот так `overflow-x: auto; width:200px;`. Не забудьте также явно указать ширину!